# ReactJS localhost Ajax call: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, localhost, reactjs

Working on the ReactJS tutorial I spinned up a local server with

```
>npm install -g http-server

>http-server -c-1
```

And got local server working fine located at http://localhost:8080

Though, when I attempted to use an AJAX call within one of my components, I got the following error in my chrome console:

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/comment.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

This is the ajax call snippet:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
                    loadCommentsFromServer: function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.props.url,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cashe: false,
                            crossDomain:true,
                            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                            success: function(data){
                                this.setState({data: data});
                            }.bind(this),
                            error: function(xhr, status, err){
                                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                            }.bind(this)
                        });
                    },
```

this.props.url is coming from here:

```
React.render(<CommentBox url="http://localhost:8080/comment.json" pollInterval={2000} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Can you post the server endpoint code? The issue is the header for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to be on the server response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` needs to be on the server response to the AJAX request (not on the client request). Here is an example of doing that on vanilla NodeJS using `http`:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  response.end('hi');
}).listen(8080);
```

For `http-server`, you can run it with `--cors` option.

Comment: Well that makes more sense. How exactly would I make that possible with `http-server`? Would comment.json just need to return the header? Could you show a javascript example?

Comment: @ApathyBear You can run `http-server` with `--cors` to enable the CORS header. You should post your server or a link to the specific tutorial you are using if that isn't a enough help.

Comment: `http-server -c-1 --cors` worked like a charm. Thank you.